# java: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libnssutil3.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure in Oracle Linux 7.5

Tags: java, oracle, nss, oim

Good day.

What need to do if the script execution leads to a problem `java: symbol lookup error /lib64/libnssutil3.so`?

I try install Oracle IDM 11gR2 (11.1.2.3) on Oracle Linux 7.5.
Already installed Oracle Databace 12c, OIM RCU, WebLogic, SOA and OAIM.
Now i try Launch WebLogic but script (/idm/oracle/fmw_oim/domains/IDM_domain/bin/startWebLogic.sh) always failed with error:

> java: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libnssutil3.so: undefined symbol: PR_GetEnvSecure

Software version:

1. Java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181
2. nss-3.36.0-5
3. nss-util-3.36.0-1

I tryed use Java-1.7 and nss-3.28.4 but error was the same.
Can you, please, help me to fix this iisue?

Comment: did you install java-64bit?

Comment: also i'd try to use oracle provided jdk

Comment: $ java -version; 
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"; 
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_181-b13); 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.181-b13, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I was blind. I deleted all versions of java (this is not necessary, but I lost my temper) and reinstall **java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.41.** After that Launch WebLogic was successful.

Scripts constantly request to java from the directory `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64/bin/java`. Despite the fact that the variable **java_home** looked like this:

> echo $ JAVA_HOME
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.181-3.b13.el7_5.x86_64

I do not know what the reason for this difference is, but as soon as the script started accessing java-1.6.0, the problem disappeared.